# Check Which object has collide with another object while scripts are same

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Two Animated car object both contains **rigid-body** and **box collider** and a **script** with **OnTriggerEnter event**.

Now I want to check that which car hit to another car while both cars are running. Means if **A hit to B or B hit to A** as both have same script and same event then, both event becomes trigger. How to identify it who hit ???

*Remember please don't recommend me to use Raycast it is expensive*

For example I made two cube added box collider and rigidbody and a script that contains(or check)

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider c) {
        Debug.Log("GameObject is : " + gameObject.name + " and collider : " + c.name);

    }
```

Now when I triggering both object the order of trigger remain same no matter i hit A object to B or B object to A. How i will differentiate it?

Comment: Difficult to assume things. I suggest post what you tried and explain  where you blocked.

Comment: a code snippet added with some details

Comment: Check for speed of the object (assume that faster is the one that hits) or use more colliders (you can hit only with the front one)

Comment: faster is the one hits i didn't get this point while for second option it can be lengthy but workable solution

Comment: @ŁukaszMotyczka but problem with second solution is i have to add four collider and four rigidbody on a single car object. performace drawback isnt it?

Comment: no surely it is not workable sorry @ŁukaszMotyczka your second option will surely down the fps

Comment: Well it actually depends on how your game is made, how many objects you have there and so on. Maybe you could post some more info/screenshot?

Comment: @ŁukaszMotyczka I have 400 hundreds cars running on different roads/path/splines. I want to check that if the two cars are colliding then stop previous car and play after some time.

Answer (score 0):

I see few ways, of which this is the easiest:

**EDIT: Note - `RigidBidy` needs to have velocity, I mean you need to move objects with `RigidBody` using `AddForce` or any other physic based movement.**

1. Checking the velocity.
   Getting `RigidBody` of every car and checking the `velocity` - the one with higher `velocity` `Vector3` is the one that hits. Note that you need to use projection here.

   ```
   void OnTriggerEnter(Collider c) 
   {
       Debug.Log("GameObject is : " + gameObject.name + " and collider : " + c.name);

       Vector3 directionB = this.transform.position - c.transform.position;
       Vector3 directionA = c.transform.position - this.transform.position;

       Vector3 rawVelocityA = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().velocity;
       Vector3 rawVelocityB = c.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().velocity;

       Vector3 realSpeedA = Vector3.Project (rawVelocityA, directionA);
       Vector3 realSpeedB = Vector3.Project (rawVelocityB, directionB);

       if (realSpeedA.magnitude > realSpeedB.magnitude) 
       {
           Debug.Log ("A hit B");
       }
       else if (realSpeedB.magnitude > realSpeedA.magnitude) 
       {
           Debug.Log ("B hit A");
       }
       else
       {
           Debug.Log ("A hit B and B hit A");
       }
   }
   ```

**EDIT: Since you are not using physics to move cars, you need to calculate speed some other way**

I suggest something like this:

Have a script SpeedCalculator.cs on each car.

```
public class SpeedCalculator : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float Velocity
    {
        get
        {
            return velocity;
        }
    }
    private float velocity;

    private Vector3 lastPosition;

    void Awake()
    {
        lastPosition = transform.position;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        velocity = transform.position - lastPosition;
        lastPosition = transform.position;
    }
}
```

And then instead of taking speed from `RigidBody` take it from `SpeedCalculator`:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider c) 
{
    Debug.Log("GameObject is : " + gameObject.name + " and collider : " + c.name);

    Vector3 directionB = this.transform.position - c.transform.position;
    Vector3 directionA = c.transform.position - this.transform.position;

    Vector3 rawVelocityA = this.GetComponent<SpeedCalculator> ().Velocity;
    Vector3 rawVelocityB = c.GetComponent<SpeedCalculator> ().Velocity;

    Vector3 realSpeedA = Vector3.Project (rawVelocityA, directionA);
    Vector3 realSpeedB = Vector3.Project (rawVelocityB, directionB);

    if (realSpeedA.magnitude > realSpeedB.magnitude) 
    {
        Debug.Log ("A hit B");
    }
    else if (realSpeedB.magnitude > realSpeedA.magnitude) 
    {
        Debug.Log ("B hit A");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log ("A hit B and B hit A");
    }
}
```

Comment: the solution didn't work i test it on two cubes it scene view it alwasy showing   A hit B and B hit A

Comment: That is suprise to me, as I don't know what could be wrong here - why length of both realSpeed vectors is equal. Are you sure the rigidBody has velocity? I quess they didn't have. I will edit the answer.

Comment: there is no velocity as i told you i am checking it in scene view by moving the direction arrow i am moving the object only for checking code

Comment: Okay, so how do you move cars? Changing rigidBody or transform directly?

Comment: car animation and cycle animation both moving on spline at one point the can collide

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan I edited the answer, now should work.

Comment: velocity = transform.position - lastPosition; do velocity is vector3 or float?